# Javascript built-in 'every' method implementation. forEach, for loop

Tags: javascript

I was trying to implement the built-in **every** method of javascript **array**.
The following are the two slightly different implementations. They take an array and a function as arguements.

```js
var every1 = function(a,fx){
  a.forEach(function(i){
    if (!fx(i)){
      return false;};
  })
 return true;}

var every2 = function(a,fx){
  for (var i in a){
    if (!fx(a[i])){
      return false;
    };
  }
 return true;}

console.log(every1([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
console.log(every2([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN));
```

They are intented to work just like the built in every function/method.
The first one is returning **true** and second one is returning **false**

Both should be false. What is wrong?

Comment: you are only returning from the inner function. you need to do a reduce or something like that.

Comment: `forEach` won't return anything. You better define an initial boolean parameter in `every1` function and let the callback of `forEach` set it's value acccordingly in each turn. Using `reduce` would be more sensible though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make it easier:

```
var every = function(data,predicateFunction) {
    for(var i=0, length = data.length;i<length;i++) {
        if(predicateFunction(data[i]) == false) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `return false` inside a `forEach` callback won't stop the iteration.

It seems you want `[].every` instead:

```js
var every = function(array, callback) {
  return array.every(function(value, index, array) {
    return callback(value);
  });
}
console.log(every([NaN, NaN, 4], isNaN)); // false
console.log(every(["abc", NaN], isNaN)); //  true
```